# can i use CGAddLineToPoint and CGAddMoveToPoint in EAGLView

Tags: iphone

Error is like this:-

errror:-CGAddLineToPoint invalid context

Answer (score 1):

I assume by EAGLView, you mean a custom UIView subclass that is backed by a CAEAGLLayer.  Because such a view has its content drawn by the OpenGL layer, you can't do the same sort of Quartz drawing within it that you would in a UIView backed with a standard CALayer.

My recommendation is to move your custom Quartz drawing to another UIView subclass, and place that UIView as a subview of your CAEAGLLayer-hosting view.